# changing font size in R DataTables (DT)

Tags: r, formatting, r-markdown, dt

Have been trying to change the font size of all text in the tables generated by DT. However, I could only figure out how to change the size of the records using
`formatStyle(names(datCalc), fontSize = '12px')`.
The column headers and buttons have text of the same size. Using R Markdown in RStudio.

Comment: Since the resulting widget is comprised of HTML, you can use CSS. The most practical way to do so depends on the context. One option is to just include a stylesheet via the RMarkdown header with sufficiently specific selectors to style it as you like.

Answer (score 25):

I think you almost got there. I solved it by explicitly telling `DT::formatStyle()` which columns I wanted. I first tried using the `names()` or `colnames()` approach, as you did. For some reason this didn't work:

```
iris %>%
  DT::datatable() %>%
  DT::formatStyle(columns = colnames(.), fontSize = '50%')
```

However, we know the `iris` dataset has 5 columns, so I just did this:

```
iris %>%
  DT::datatable() %>%
  DT::formatStyle(columns = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), fontSize = '50%')
```

In this case, I use `font-size = 50%`, but you can also specify `font-size = 12pt` as you did. You can also supply logical vectors like `c(T, F, F, F, T)` to the `columns` argument, and the formatting will apply to those columns for which you have stated `TRUE`.

Comment: The reason `colnames(.)` didn't work is that the pipe doesn't return `iris` but whatever `DT::datatable()` returns (i.e. a list). If you write `colnames(iris)` it works.

Comment: This doesn't really work; it only changes the fontsize for text inside the table, not for the whole table.

Answer (score 14):

Adding CSS through a javascript table header call seems to do the trick (i.e 'this.api().table().header()' ).

```
datatable(..., options=list(
  initComplete = JS(
        "function(settings, json) {",
        "$(this.api().table().header()).css({'font-size': '50%'});",
        "}")))
  )
```

Citation: Section 4.3 @ https://rstudio.github.io/DT/options.html

Answer (score 12):

Building on the answers given by Antex and sabeepa. If you want to change the font size of everything, including the DT components outside of the table itself, use the `table().container()`. So the code would look like this:

```
font.size <- "10pt"

df %>% 
   DT::datatable(
     options=list(
       initComplete = htmlwidgets::JS(
          "function(settings, json) {",
          paste0("$(this.api().table().container()).css({'font-size': '", font.size, "'});"),
          "}")
       ) 
     )
```

Answer (score 8):

Was able to change the header and the footer by changing the CSS with the JS table and column content font size with the `formatStyle` as follows. However, the header and the footer font size stayed the same. I would like to change header/footer/body (entire font for the table) in one swoop. Is that possible?

```
datatable(head(iris, 20), options = list(
  initComplete = JS(
    "function(settings, json) {",
    "$(this.api().table().header()).css({'font-size': '5px', 'background-color': '#c2d1f0', 'color': '#fff'});",
    "}"))) %>%  formatStyle(columns = colnames(.$x$data), `font-size` = '12px')
```

Attempted to update CSS for columns with the following command without success

```
"$(this.api().columns().data()).css({'font-size': '5px'});"

"$(this.api().table().footer()).css({'font-size': '10px});"

"$(this.api().tables().body()).css({'font-size': '10px'});"
```