# R DT datatable font size change

Tags: css, r, datatable, dt

I want to change the font size of the entire data table., The default size is too large for what I want to display.  I am trying to change the font-size of variable names and column content with `formatStyle` as follows

```
library(DT)
library(magrittr)
iris %>% 
     datatable() %>% 
     formatStyle(columns = colnames(.), `font-size` = '25%')
```

But, what is rendered is the same font size regardless of the changes. Tried different formats for font-size such as 'large, small' '150%, 50%' and '10px,20px,30px'

Comment: columns = colnames(.$x$data)

Answer (score 0):

This question has already been addressed [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44101055/changing-font-size-in-r-datatables-dt)

To accomplish what you are trying to do:

```
library(DT)
library(magrittr)
iris %>% 
  datatable() %>% 
  DT::formatStyle(columns = colnames(iris), fontSize = '25%')
```

Answer (score 0):

Was able to change the font-size for header and the columns by updating the CSS. The table header with JS api and the column content font size with the formatStyle as follows. However, the header and the footer font size stayed the same. I would like to change header/footer/body (entire font for the table) in one swoop. Is that possible?

```
datatable(head(iris, 20), options = list(
  initComplete = JS(
    "function(settings, json) {",
    "$(this.api().table().header()).css({'font-size': '5px', 'background-color': '#c2d1f0', 'color': '#fff'});",
    "}"))) %>%  formatStyle(columns = colnames(.$x$data), `font-size` = '12px')
```

Attempted to update CSS for columns with the following command without success

```
"$(this.api().columns().data()).css({'font-size': '5px'});"

"$(this.api().table().footer()).css({'font-size': '10px});"

"$(this.api().tables().body()).css({'font-size': '10px'});"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
datatable(head(iris, 20), options = list(
  initComplete = JS("
                        function(settings, json) {
                          $(this.api().table().header()).css({
                          'font-size': '12px',
                          });
                        }
                    ")
)) %>%
  formatStyle(columns = colnames(.$x$data), `font-size` = "12px")
```